# Kohana - Check if model exists (Not a record)

Tags: php, orm, model, kohana

I want to check, if a model in Kohana exists - or not! I load the models by using the ORM.

My current code:

```
// Load model
$myModel = ORM::factory('mymodel')->where('id', '=', 1);
```

In this case, the ORM try to load the model - but i am pretty sure, that the model won't exists, because i have not created this so far. But this is okay. Instead to try load the first record, i have to check, if the model exists - maybe with another ORM function?

I know, you can use `ORM::factory('mymodel')->where('id', '=', 1)->loaded()` for checking a single record / result. When i try to fetch the first record, my kohana throws an exception, indeed..

How do you guys check, if a model exists, or not?

Answer (score 1):

```
//loading model
$myModel = ORM::factory('mymodel')->where('id', '=', 1)->find();
```

I think you missed `find` method in chain.

then you can check if model is loaded like you wanted

```
//checking if loaded
if ($myModel->loaded()) {
```

**edit**

to figure out if model exists

```
try {
   //loading model
   $myModel = ORM::factory('mymodel')->where('id', '=', 1);
   //more logic
} catch ($e) { //or you can define exception which throws ORM::factory
   //doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Won't work for me. The ORM has a short syntax. `ORM::factory('mymodel')->where('id', '=', 1)->find();` is exactly the same as `ORM::factory('mymodel')->where('id', '=', 1)`.. I the case, you try to build the model with the ORM factory, Kohana will throw this exception, because the ORM can't find the model..

Comment: then use `try` and `catch` blocks

Comment: you can check if class exists, in `KO3` there's no namespace so it's easy

Comment: Try `find_all()` after `count` your object.

Answer (score 1):

```php
empty(Kohana::find_file('classes', 'model/customer')) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP and future visitors to SO why you did what you did.

Comment: find_file searches for a file in the Cascading Filesystem, 
and returns the path to the file that has the highest precedence, 
so that it can be included. 
http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Kohana#find_file

Answer (score 1):

Well, The model is a class. You can check with [class_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) if "Model_Mymodal" is loaded in PHP

```
if(class_exists("Model_Mymodel"))
{
    // Do something
}
```